# Eclipse Compiling Java Code Error - Compiler is null

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I am newb to android development. I need to compile a java code on eclipse my system was set up to do it. but all of a sudden my pc crashed so I need to setup the new system. I downloaded Jre installed. set up JAVA_HOME variable in my win 2008 r2 machine and downloaded Eclipse Kepler Release and then I try to build the project.

the project has some cmds

cmd /c %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -jar template.jar dataProvider.java=..\gen\com\data\dataProvider.java -refresh

but though everything looks like how it was before I was using eclipse juno and jre 6 I guess but now when I build I get the following error.

Compiler is null

Since I am not sure what I missed or the JRE is wrong. I would like some help setting up my machine.

Thanks
Appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to compile java, you need the `JDK`, not the `JRE`.

Comment: Ok so Java_home is JDK path? I did install JDK but it did not work but I set the home to JRE. Should I change?

Comment: yes jre is use to run the application not to develop

Comment: and also try to set the JDK lib. path as environment variable not JRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download JDK.exe and install and then set the environment variable check to the comment what Joachim is telling